# Determine if $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(1+e^{-x})} \ dx$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Determine if $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(1+e^{-x})} \ dx$$ converges.

I guess I have to use the comparison test for integrals to determine this? Somehow this feels like it would converge as the denominator gets arbitary large the integrand approaches $0$. So finding an upper bound for the integrand $\frac{1}{x(1+e^{-x})}$ that converges would imply that this converges also? Initially I thought that $\frac{1}{x(1+e^{-x})} \le \frac1x$ since the exponent will just tend to zero, but $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac1x \ dx \to \infty$$ which against what I wanted to show. Any hints on this?

Comment: Hint: it diverges.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how did you manage to conclude this?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x(1+e^{-x})}\ge\frac1{2x}$$
so the integral diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  if $x$ is large, $1+e^{-x} \lt 2$

Comment: And even when it's not large.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the other side inequality as well. As $x>0$, we have $e^{-x}<1$ and therefore

$$
\frac{1}{2x} < \frac{1}{x(1+e^{-x})}.
$$

Now evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^*$ you should see how the integrand behaves near $0$ and $\infty$.
Near $x=0$: $\frac{1}{x(1+e^{-x})} \sim \frac{1}{2x}$ and near $+\infty$  $\frac{1}{x(1+e^{-x})} \sim \frac{1}{x}$.
So your integral diverges at both ends by comparison with a Riemann integral.